# ngrepeat does not iterate $ attribute

Tags: angularjs

I tried filtering with an object and to print out the filters via `ng-repeat = (key, value)` in object.

As I tried various [filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), I saw that `ng-repeat` does not seem to work with the object's `$` attribute, which is pretty useful if you are filtering.

Is there a possibility to show all attributes of the filtering objects automatically even if you use `$`

[This link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzOqlw4Og3yKnPct9zT6) shows it doesn't seem to work with objects starting with $

```
  $scope.testObj = {};

  $scope.testObj.test = 'test';
  $scope.testObj.$ = '$';
  $scope.testObj.$test = '$test';

  <div ng-repeat = "(key, value) in testObj">
    <p>{{key}}: {{value}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: I'm interested why would you have $ in your attribute name?

Comment: Filters: "A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object or its nested object properties. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above. " https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: That is a filter's input, though, not a property that is being repeated.  So, you would use it like: `ng-repeat="(key, value) in testObj | filter:{$:'any'}"`.

Comment: yeah, the filter itself works just fine, so it is not in the plnkr, but i also want to show the filter in another ng-repeat, so that you can see the search criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS doesn't support it yet. There is an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6266).

However you can make it work with a little code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var getProperties = function(input){
     var result = [];

     for(var propertyName in input) {
       result.push({key : propertyName, value : input[propertyName]});
     }

    return result;
  };


  $scope.testObj = {};
  $scope.testObj.test = 'test';
  $scope.testObj.$ = '$';
  $scope.testObj.$whatever = '$whatever';

  $scope.testObjProperties = getProperties($scope.testObj);

});
```

Then display it in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="property in testObjProperties">
    <p>{{property.key}} : {{property.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Here's a working plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/LFrfLcpoOg0ScEY89p25?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `ng-repeat` filters out object properties that begin with `$`.

This is from [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L3):

```
    for (var itemKey in collection) {
      if (collection.hasOwnProperty(itemKey) && itemKey.charAt(0) != '$') {
        collectionKeys.push(itemKey);
      }
    }
```

This is most likely due to the fact that Angular uses `$` to indicate code that is *internal* to the Angular library.

It seems this will only occur if you are using `ng-repeat` over an object.

Comment: Would a valid work around be to use HTML Number codes for the symbol? I.e. `&#36;` For a `$` sign in this case

Comment: No, that is not valid JavaScript.  A JavaScript property cannot begin with `&`.  There shouldn't be a need to do this with `ng-repeat`.  If you can an object that could not be used,  you should map to another structure before passing to `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I meant for the value... I wasn't suggesting `$scope` be replaced with `&#36;scope`

Comment: The value can be whatever you want.  This is only an issue with an object's key.

Comment: Ah right, I see the problem now. Was just reading his code wrong

Answer (score 0):

I see them being disallowed specifically in the code:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L341

There are no comments around, and I agree this looks more than a bug than a feature, to me.  Isn't that what marking properties as non-enumerable and `Object.keys` is for?
Browser compatibility hell, may be the reason, as always.